# Getting Error, when Forms App(iOS) goes inactive/sleep/lock mode, After Making HTTPWebRequest

Tags: xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest

Getting the following Error,
"Error getting response stream (Read Done1): ReceiveFailure"
When the Xamarin Forms App makes a HttpWebRequest to server, and then App goes to sleep/inactive/autolock screen mode before getting the HTTPResponse.

how to handle this or Is there an option to be enabled/set for supporting this.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you app goes to background, ios move it to suspended mode if you have not specified somewhere that you are executing background task. You can use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask ("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration)`  for informing ios about your task.

You can read good tutorial about it from [here](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/)